# Как добавить параметр при входе на страницу, но без повторного входа уже с наличием?

Tags: php, html, mysql

У меня есть сайт. При нажатии на кнопку-ссылку из меню пользователя перекидывает в /profile

Но как сделать чтобы, при входе в /profile добавлялся параметр id (?id=айди пользователя из базы данных)

А когда пользователя перенаправило в ссылку с параметром (/profile?id=айди пользователя из базы данных) /profile больше никуда не перекидывает

Но при постоянном заходе на /profile пользователя будет перекидывать на страницу с его айди и данными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это пользовательский профиль, авторизированный в системе и совершающий переход, то просто добавьте его ID из сессии и он всегда будет попадать в его профиль.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста продемонстрировать это на коде, а то мой мозг уже вскипает и я ничего не понимаю

Comment: "https://your_site/profile/" .'/'. $_SESSION['user_id']

Comment: Это если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос

Comment: Ну не совсем, мне нужно не при нажатии на кнопку, а при входе на страницу profile

Comment: Тогда можете записать нужный Вам url или id пользователя в localStorage, там данные хранятся вечно. При заходе на страницу извлекать его и делать редирект

Comment: но ведь localStorage не безопасен

Comment: Спасибо тебе! Пусть даже способ не безопасен, так как извлекается через eval, но я его переделаю. А так всё работает.